# ASP.NET MVC authentication on groups

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm implementing an `ASP.NET MVC` web application just for fun. In my application, users can log in and join groups. I have a user authentication which works, where I inherit the `identityUser`. But I'd also like to authenticate the groups, i.e. if user tries to join a group, he would have to know the groups password to be able to join the group.

The entity model for the groups is like that:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string groupName { get; set; }    <-- this is unique
public string Password { get; set; }
```

The view model would be similar but with `[Required]` attribute and what follows the View model.

But what I'm having trouble with is how I can authenticate the groups, have the passwordhash and check if password is valid and so on?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

My view when registering group:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
         <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

My group view model:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Then I'm wondering how the controller should be so it'll authenticate the group.

```
[HttpPost, Authorize]
public ActionResult CreateLeague(RegisterGroupViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);
    // check here if password is okay, and also hash it  <-- here is my problem
    // I've implemented if group is free to create, and create the group in the database.. which would be here below, no need to show it here.
}
```

Comment: This is a quite a broad question, I'd be tempted to say _too broad_ without much of the code you've tried so far.  There should be plenty of questions on SO that answer your password hash/check question, but there are many ways to go about checking for your group authentication, set a session variable and check that they are validated or add the user to a role and use `[Authorize(Role = "MyGroup")]` to check it on your controller/actions?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and that is true - this is quite a broad question. I'll edit my question and insert some code which I've tried.